# laravel between dates from_date and to_date

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I am working in Laravel.

- Presently, I am working in an attendance module.
- my problem is leaving application, first I am applied to leave `from_date`
  to `to_date`.
- Next, I am going same dates apply I through error.
- and middle date applies through error. This two conditions OK.
- but I apply to leave bellow `from_date` and after `to_date`. This condition
  is not taken

how to  calculate this condition. my code below please check

```
$keyWithData = DB::table('leave_allocations')
     ->select('employee','leave_type','name')
     ->where('leave_allocations.from_date','<=',$dateS->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00")
     ->where('leave_allocations.to_date','>=',$dateS->format('Y-m-d')." 00:00:00")
     ->where('leave_allocations.from_date','<=',$dateE)
     ->where('leave_allocations.to_date','>=',$dateE)
     ->where('leave_allocations.employee',$empdata->name)
     ->where('leave_allocations.leave_type',$type)
     ->first();
```

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is `whereBetween()` and `orWhereBetween()`

```
$keyWithData = DB::table('leave_allocations')
    ->select('employee','leave_type','name')
    ->where(function($query) use($dateS, $dateE) {
        $query->whereBetween('from_date', [
            $dateS->format('m-d-Y 00:00:00'), 
            $dateE->format('m-d-Y 00:00:00')
        ])
        ->orWhereBetween('to_date', [
            $dateS->format('m-d-Y 00:00:00'),
            $dateE->format('m-d-Y 00:00:00')
        ]);
    })
    ->where([
        ['leave_allocations.employee',$empdata->name].
        ['leave_allocations.leave_type',$type]
    ])
    ->first();
```

**Another approach using a date range**

```
// create a period object between new leaves start date and end date.
$period = new \DatePeriod(
    $dateS,
    new \DateInterval('P1D'),
    $dateE
);

// all the days between new leave start date and end date.
$new_leave_dates = [];

foreach ($period as $key => $value) {
   array_push($dates, $value->format('Y-m-d'));
}

// get all the rows without those days.
$keyWithData = DB::table('leave_allocations')
    ->select('employee','leave_type','name')
    ->whereNotIn('from_date', $new_leave_dates)
    ->where([
        ['leave_allocations.employee',$empdata->name].
        ['leave_allocations.leave_type',$type]
    ])
    ->first();
```

Comment: This is ok .But how to work before date and after dates.

Comment: Supose i apply leave in first time this dates 1/10/2018 to 31/10/2018

Comment: next i apply leave in 29/09/2018 to 01/11/2018 .This dates through error.your condition is not work in this dates

Comment: exceed dates middle dates are equal how to work please explain.

Comment: oh I get it, it's pretty easy to achieve in another approach, I will update the answer

Comment: ok,Thanks.iam write in difference dates foreach this is ok.or any other methods

Comment: It can't be, but I added another solution Just for your choice.

Comment: Thanks **Tharaka Dilshan**  your valuable suggestion.